VBA: Copy all data from HTML file into Excel Spreadsheet
We have a bunch of standard reports that are generated in an HTML format. These are very easy to manually copy and paste into Excel (simple Control+A, Control+C, Control+V does it) however I would like to make this a little bit more user friendly by doing it all through a Button and Macro.
The Macro needs to open up an explorer window for the user to locate the respective file to have copy and pasted, on clicking "Open" on said file the entire contents need to be copy and pasted into a specific worksheet in my template.
For reference, the Worksheet to be pasted into is "Nav Shortage Report" and the data needs to be pasted into "A1" (note: just a simple copy and paste so the text goes across multiple cells, I do not need all data to be in one cell).
Code I have so far is:
Sub Open_Navision_Shortage_List()
    
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenDocument As Variant
            
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Navision Shortage List", FileFilter:="HMTL Files,*.htm*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenDocument = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenDocument.Sheets(1).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Nav Shortage Report").Range("A1").Paste
        OpenDocument.Close False
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
End Sub

This enables me to select the HTML file, however I get a "Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method" error on the statement ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Nav Shortage Report").Range("A1").Paste
Thanks in advance.

OpenDocument.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Nav Shortage Report").Range("A1")
